# git gc: error: Could not read 0000000000000000000000000000000000000000

Tags: git

```
git gc
error: Could not read 0000000000000000000000000000000000000000
Enumerating objects: 147323, done.
Counting objects: 100% (147323/147323), done.
Delta compression using up to 4 threads
Compressing objects: 100% (36046/36046), done.
Writing objects: 100% (147323/147323), done.
Total 147323 (delta 91195), reused 147323 (delta 91195), pack-reused 0
```

What is going on here? Should I worry or ignore the the problem?

For example `git gc --help` and similar have nothing that appears to explain the problem.

[`git fsck` report](https://gist.github.com/matkoniecz/41fe09efd620d73f728a9058c92404f7)

I am running git version 2.35.1 on Lubuntu 20.04.

Comment: What `git fsck` is saying ?

Comment: Also what OS and Git version are you using?

Comment: @VonC 
I am running git version 2.35.1 on Lubuntu 20.04.

Comment: @Ôrel See https://gist.github.com/matkoniecz/41fe09efd620d73f728a9058c92404f7

Comment: Did you rename branch(es)? I had to update `.git/refs/remotes/origin/HEAD` after renaming my main branch.

Comment: What did you do to have so many dangling object after git gc ?

Comment: @Ôrel No idea. It is a long lived repository with plenty branches, rebases, cancelled rebases, `git reset --hard` etc.

Comment: The `git fsck` output looks fine. It looks like `git gc` is finding a null-OID ref somewhere, but `git fsck` doesn't, so that's something of a mystery. The null-OID ref is preventing `git gc` from doing everything it should, so that's why there are dangling commits and blobs: they're *normal* in an active repo.

Comment: Another data point. The error occurs when `git gc` calls `git reflog expire --all` internally. I see the error in one of my repositories, too. Investigating...

Comment: Current fix in progress: https://public-inbox.org/git/83d1c3cc-e281-4455-60d4-ead53d578bb8@kdbg.org/

Answer (score 32, accepted):

This error is harmless in the sense that it does not indicate a broken repository. It is a bug that was introduced in Git 2.35 and that should be fixed in later releases.
[Edit: This regression was fixed in Git 2.36.0.]

The worst that can happen is that `git gc` does not prune all objects that are referenced from reflogs.
The error is triggered by an invocation of `git reflog expire --all` that `git gc` does behind the scenes.

The trigger are empty reflog files in the `.git/logs` directory structure that were left behind after a branch was deleted. As a workaround you can remove these empty files. This command lets you find them and check their size:

```
find .git/logs -type f -size 0c | xargs ls -ld
```

Pick only the files that do not correspond to a branch.
(Also, I am uncertain about the operation of `-size 0c`, hence, do make sure not to remove all the listed files blindly, but only those that have no corresponding branch and are actually empty.)

This issue was [forwarded](https://public-inbox.org/git/571c0796-66d4-e8c7-c5a5-2e7a28132aa9@kdbg.org/) to git mailing list based on this SO question and [is being solved](https://public-inbox.org/git/83d1c3cc-e281-4455-60d4-ead53d578bb8@kdbg.org/).

Comment: Is there maybe some ticket on issue tracker that can be monitored?

Comment: No, there is not issue tracker for Git. You would have to monitor the mailing list. I'll update this answer when the fix appears in a public release.

Comment: @reducingactivity https://public-inbox.org/git/83d1c3cc-e281-4455-60d4-ead53d578bb8@kdbg.org/

Comment: @j6t Thanks for forwarding this bug to git mailing list!